# How to resume AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask on the next launch?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am using AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask to download the video content for offline playback. If during the download user quits the app I need a way to resume the download on the next launch. With the AVAssetDownloadTask API Apple used to provide a way to supply the destination folder (see this question: [How to resume AVAssetDownloadTask after restarting app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40305346/1203625)), but this API is now deprecated. There is no hint about the new way to resume the task in the docs.

Comment: I think it still does not work. Did you managed to solve the issue? I created an example to test it: https://github.com/mackode/AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask_Resume

Comment: @mackode Have you found a solution? I'm in same situation here, trying to restore download after app relaunch

Comment: @PeteStreem Unfortunately, to my current knowledge, it is not possible to resume AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask :/. (from the user perspective) The app has to be at least backgrounded during the whole download. (from the system perspective) System still can manage the app state in the background, so it can be respawn, but cannot be terminated by the user action.

Comment: @mackode I managed to resume download task, described it a little bit here. But have a little bit another problem. You can track here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762319/resume-hls-download-with-changed-url-avassetdownloadurlsession

Answer (score 1):

For my Play - pause functionality for AVAggregateAssetDownlodTask based on project from [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams)

I managed to pause and resume a download with this code.

**Pause**

```
/// Pauses an AVAssetDownloadTask given an Asset.
/// - Tag: PauseDownload
func pauseDownload(for asset: Asset) {
  var task: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask?
  for (taskKey, assetVal) in activeDownloadsMap where asset == assetVal {
       task = taskKey
       task?.suspend()
       break
   }
// asset.setState(mediaDownloadState: MediaDownloadState.paused) // this is personal, I added a state enum in Asset class so I can keep track state, it's optional
}
```

**Resume**

```
/// Pauses an AVAssetDownloadTask given an Asset.
 /// - Tag: ResumeDownload
func resumeDownload(for asset: Asset) {
        var task: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask?
        for (taskKey, assetVal) in activeDownloadsMap where asset == assetVal {
            task = taskKey
            task?.resume()
            break
        }
        // asset.setState(mediaDownloadState: MediaDownloadState.downloading) same as before.. 
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share code to process on relaunch to resume pending download? Have tried it in 
assetDownloadURLSession.getAllTasks { [weak self] tasksArray in 
}

Comment: @Paresh.P Have you found a solution? I'm in same situation here, trying to restore download after app relaunch